# How would i stop my timer?

Tags: java, user-interface, timer, jframe, actionlistener

So i made a timer class for a game ive created and i already have the start button action set to start the timer, but i am a bit confused as to how to stop the timer and to reset it back to 0. Would be great if anyone could give any solutions to my problem.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MyTimer extends Panel {


private JLabel timeDisplay;
private JButton resetButton;
private JButton startButton;
private JButton stopButton;
Timer timer;

public MyTimer(){

    MyTimer timer;
    startButton = new JButton("Start Timer");
    stopButton = new JButton("Stop Timer");
    timeDisplay = new JLabel("...Waiting...");
    resetButton = new JButton("Reset Timer");

    this.add(resetButton);
    this.add(startButton);
    this.add(stopButton);
    this.add(timeDisplay);

    event e = new event();
    startButton.addActionListener(e);

    event1 c = new event1();
    stopButton.addActionListener(c);

    event2 d = new event2();
    resetButton.addActionListener(d);

}

public class event implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        int count = 0;
        timeDisplay.setText("Elapsed Time in Seconds: " + count);

        TimeClass tc = new TimeClass(count);
        timer = new Timer(1000, tc);
        timer.start();
    }
}

public class TimeClass implements ActionListener{
    int counter;

    public TimeClass(int counter){

        this.counter = counter;

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        counter++;

        timeDisplay.setText("Elapsed Time in Seconds: " + counter);

    }
}

class event1 implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent c){
        timer.stop();
    }
}

class event2 implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent d){
        timer.restart();
    }
}
}
```

**EDIT**

Ok so i have the stop button doing what it needs to do perfectly, but the reset button has a problem. it pauses the timer for a second before resuming to count up from where it was paused, ex: it would pause at 4 seconds for a second before continuing to 5, 6, etc.

Any suggestions?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MyTimer extends Panel {


    private JLabel timeDisplay;
    private JButton resetButton;
    private JButton startButton;
    private JButton stopButton;
    Timer timer;

    public MyTimer(){

        MyTimer timer;
        startButton = new JButton("Start Timer");
        stopButton = new JButton("Stop Timer");
        timeDisplay = new JLabel("...Waiting...");
        resetButton = new JButton("Reset Timer");

        this.add(resetButton);
        this.add(startButton);
        this.add(stopButton);
        this.add(timeDisplay);

        event e = new event();
        startButton.addActionListener(e);

        event1 c = new event1();
        stopButton.addActionListener(c);

        event2 d = new event2();
        resetButton.addActionListener(d);

    }

    public class event implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            int count = 0;
            timeDisplay.setText("Elapsed Time in Seconds: " + count);

            TimeClass tc = new TimeClass(count);
            timer = new Timer(1000, tc);
            timer.start();
        }
    }

    public class TimeClass implements ActionListener{
        int counter;

        public TimeClass(int counter){

            this.counter = counter;

        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            counter++;

            timeDisplay.setText("Elapsed Time in Seconds: " + counter);

        }
    }

    class event1 implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent c){
            timer.stop();
        }
    }

    class event2 implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent d){
            timer.restart();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call its .[restart()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#restart%28%29) method to .. restart it. And .stop() to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at sample code on [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

use `timer.restart()` to restart it again and `timer.stop()` to stop it.